# How to track DOM change in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension where I want to fetch all the images exist on a page but some of the images load after some time (may be through ajax) which I could not fetch once the DOM is idle. Is there any way to track the DOM change after the page is loaded?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [document.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) with the [DOMNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) event. Your callback will have to check each node insertion to see if it is the type of node you are looking for. Something like the following should work.

```
function nodeInsertedCallback(event) {
    console.log(event);
};
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', nodeInsertedCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks abraham. It worked. For those who do not know were to put the above code: http://reminiscential.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/building_google_reader_plugin/

Comment: Heads up: this event is **deprecated**. The modern way is to use DOM mutation observers, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242/934239) is the canonical answer.

Answer (score 36):

*Updated for 2020:*

The recommended way nowadays is to use the [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API.

```
 let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    for(let mutation of mutations) {
         for(let addedNode of mutation.addedNodes) {
             if (addedNode.nodeName === "IMG") {
                 console.log("Inserted image", addedNode);
              }
          }
     }
 });
 observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: This code should be added to background.js?

Comment: This should be in a content script. Only content scripts can access the DOM.

Comment: You mean content scripts can only access the DOM. Right?