# Chrome Extensions in Gmail, autosave removes it

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, autosave

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that is used in the GMail compose screen. So far I have it working the way I want to except that when the GMail does its auto-save it removes my extension.

I'm adding in my extension with the content_script via java inject. and appending to the compose iframe.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to track DOM changes and re-add your code after the auto-save. There is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882502/how-to-track-dom-change-in-chrome-extension/8887226) that gives a quick intro to `DOMNodeInserted` events. You should be able to watch for the `Draft saved at ...` insert.