# Trigger a function in a Chrome extension when a Google Calendar Event is opened / updated

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I started building a Google Calendar Add-on, which I would like to migrate to a Chrome extension (to have more flexibility for the UI). In Google Scripts add-ons, one can define a trigger function that executes whenever a calendar event is created / updated (see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/calendar-addons#eventopentrigger)).

Do you know how I can have a similar behaviour in a Chrome extension? Basically, I would like to define a function to be called whenever the user opens / updates an event (such as in the picture below).

I am very new to front-end dev so any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

[image]

I researched the Google Calendar API documentation extensively but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: I don't think there is a calendar onOpen event in apps script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to developing Chrome Extensions myself, so I may be missing something, but I do not think you are able to define triggers in that way with Extension. You're usually just sending messages between the `Content` and `Background` pages.

All that being said, you might be able to get what you need from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891029/13771937). I haven't tried it within a Chrome Extension myself, but I just tried it out in the Chrome console while on the Google Calendar page and I did get a lot of notifications immediately when I  clicked on my calendar to open an event. The "Create an Event" window is enclosed within a "span" element, so that's how I defined the MutationObserver:

```
 let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    for(let mutation of mutations) {
         for(let addedNode of mutation.addedNodes) {
             if (addedNode.nodeName === "SPAN") {
                 console.log("Create a Calendar Opened", addedNode);
              }
          }
     }
 });
 observer.observe(document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

You'll probably need to fiddle around with the node selector to get exactly what you want though.